# Even though uesEffect dependency state doesn't change, it executes useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have below code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortData !== undefined && sortData !== null) {
      console.log("sortdata", sortData);
      setLoading(true);
      console.log("loading", loading);
    }
  }, [sortData]);
```

so if `sortData` state changes, {...} containing two console, will be executed.

But when I console.log this, result comes below.

[image]

it seems weird for me.

Because sortData is same as [] then sortData state doesn't change, so it should not run this useEffect, doesn't it?

But it keep printing console "sortdata" and "loading"..

why it happen?

I am the beginner, please explain me in detail.

---

**Detail explanation**

I have created below code to execute useEffect mutually impacted.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      perioddata !== undefined &&
      perioddata !== null &&
      initialuser.length !== 0
    ) {
      setResultData(resultDateFunc(perioddata));
    }
  }, [perioddata, initialuser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resultData !== undefined && resultData !== null) {
      setSortData(criteriaSortFunc(resultData));
    }
  }, [resultData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortData !== undefined && sortData !== null) {
      console.log("sortdata", sortData);
      setLoading(true);
      console.log("loading", loading);
    }
  }, [sortData]);
```

as you can see **perioddata changes -> resultdata changes -> sortdata changes -> then change loading state** from false to true.

So it will draw the page.

Problem is that each useEffect is executed not only dependency changes but also page refreshes, so i guess, loading state changes from false to true even when sortdata is not ready as I expected.

How can I make loading state changes only when sortdata is ready?

Comment: How do you define `sortData`? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: @HenryWoody I add more explanation in detail

Comment: Looks like `sortData` is updating (although would need to see the definition for `perioddata` as well to be sure), but perhaps the root of the confusion here is that two arrays with identical contents (in this case empty) are not necessarily equal, they may have distinct identities (try it with `[] === []`), so maybe look over your code once more with that in mind.

Comment: I add more explanation, my question is not related to if conditional. even if doesn't have that conditional, my question remains still same :)

Comment: Under the hood `useEffect` is using a conditional to check whether the values in the dependency array are the same. Understanding that arrays that look the same may not be equal is fundamental to understanding why `useEffect` runs when it does.

Answer (score 1):

This could indicate that your parent component triggers it.

So if this component's parent components gets a fresh re-render, it can cause this child component rendering it again. So each time you see `sortdata []` it may not be the `[sortData]` gets changed, but the whole component gets re-rendered by its parent component.

Also how do you pass the èmpty `[]` from parent component? If you passing this one from a func e.g. `filter()`, then you ended up with a new object of `[]` so each time the `[]` is different each time created (`[]` is an object, not a string or number)

Comment: thanks. i understand. then can I execute useEffect 'only when' this dependency state changes? not impacted by parent state.

Comment: You can't, because the component is literally being removed from the page, then added back, so it's a new component every time.  You need to put your useEffect in the parent component.